# Extracting data from object into a table of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have a response object, which looks like this:

```
const response = {
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\compressed.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '99.21' }],
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\large.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '98.29' }],
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\small.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '99.42' }]
}
```

I want to convert this object to this:

```
["G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\compressed.jpg, bear, 99.25", "G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\large.jpg, bear, 98.29",
"G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\small.jpg, bear, 99.42"]
```

I need to convert it like this because I will use this data in a `.csv` file.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries`, `Object.values`, `map` & `join`, for a long one liner. This will work for any object, but it will disregard its keys:

```js
const response = {
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\compressed.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '99.21' }],
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\large.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '98.29' }],
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\small.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '99.42' }]
}

const csv = Object.entries(response).map(([k, v]) => [k, ...Object.values(v[0])].join(', '))

console.log(csv)
```

Answer (score -2):

For a single looped, easily read solution:

```js
const response = {
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\compressed.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '99.21' }],
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\large.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '98.29' }],
    'G:\\magisterka\\master-project\\animals\\bear\\with\\4\\small.jpg': [{ name: 'bear', confidence: '99.42' }]
}

const parsed = Object.keys(response).map(key => {
  const val = response[key][0]
  return `${key}, ${val.name}, ${val.confidence}`
})

console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.